# How to model data of a multidimensional array with different hierarchy

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I am working with an expansion tile in a flutter that shows user information in an irregular hierarchical order.

I am optimizing the code to increase the performance of the expansion tile widget. Unit-III hierarchy differs from the rest and I am having a difficult time creating data classes from it. Any reference to dealing with multidimensional arrays effectively will be very helpful.

JSON:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "1. UNIT-I CALCULUS": {
            "1.1 Limit and Continuity": {
                "is_lesson": true,
                "lesson_detail": [
                    {
                        "title": "Eg 1",
                        "lesson_id": "34670",
                        "course_id": "126",
                        "section_id": "2145",
                        "duration": "00:01:08",
                        "is_lesson_free": "0",
                        "video_url": "https://lb.mero.school/api/v1/video/retrieve_path/7f1814c2-bc5a-48b7-9b5a-4e493f564a03",
                        "video_type": "bulk_videos",
                        "attachment_type": "url",
                        "attachment": null
                    }
                ],
                "2. UNIT-II ALGEBRA": {
                    "2.1 Complex Numbers": {
                        "is_lesson": true,
                        "lesson_detail": [
                            {
                                "title": "Eg 1",
                                "lesson_id": "37069",
                                "course_id": "126",
                                "section_id": "2145",
                                "duration": "00:02:32",
                                "is_lesson_free": "0",
                                "video_url": "https://lb.mero.school/api/v1/video/retrieve_path/d42d03a3-c857-4e99-8439-edbda003d296",
                                "video_type": "bulk_videos",
                                "attachment_type": "url",
                                "attachment": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "3. UNIT-III VECTOR ALGEBRA": {
                    "is_lesson": true,
                    "lesson_detail": [
                        {
                            "title": "Q. 1",
                            "lesson_id": "33898",
                            "course_id": "126",
                            "section_id": "2145",
                            "duration": "00:02:42",
                            "is_lesson_free": "0",
                            "video_url": "https://lb.mero.school/api/v1/video/retrieve_path/5c6487a2-a3df-4175-b20c-57134d2684dd",
                            "video_type": "bulk_videos",
                            "attachment_type": "url",
                            "attachment": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

SectionDemoData sectionDemoDataFromMap(String str) =>
    SectionDemoData.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String sectionDemoDataToMap(SectionDemoData data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class SectionDemoData {
  SectionDemoData({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  final bool status;
  final String message;
  final SubSection data;

  factory SectionDemoData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SectionDemoData(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: SubSection.fromMap(json["data"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": data.toMap(),
      };
}

class SubSection {
  SubSection({
    required this.lessonList,
    required this.lessonName,
    isLessonItself = false,
  });

  final List<Lesson> lessonList;
  final List<String> lessonName;
  bool isLessonItself = false;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'lessonList': lessonList.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList()});

    return result;
  }

  factory SubSection.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    map.forEach(
      (key, value) {
        if (isLessonItself) print("KEY HERR:" + value);
      },
    );
    return SubSection(
      lessonName: List<String>.from(map => map.Key),
      lessonList:
          List.generate(map.keys.length, (index) => Lesson.fromMap(map[index])),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory SubSection.fromJson(String source) =>
      SubSection.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  @override
  String toString() => 'SubSection(lesson: ,lessonList: $lessonList)';
}

class Lesson {
  Lesson({
    required this.isLesson,
    required this.lessonDetailList,
  });

  final bool isLesson;
  final List<LessonDetail> lessonDetailList;

  factory Lesson.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Lesson(
        isLesson: json["is_lesson"],
        lessonDetailList: List<LessonDetail>.from(
            json["lesson_detail"].map((x) => LessonDetail.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "is_lesson": isLesson,
        "lesson_detail":
            List<dynamic>.from(lessonDetailList.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class LessonDetail {
  LessonDetail({
    required this.title,
    required this.lessonId,
    required this.courseId,
    required this.sectionId,
    required this.duration,
    required this.isLessonFree,
    required this.videoUrl,
    required this.videoType,
    required this.attachmentType,
    required this.attachment,
  });

  final String title;
  final String lessonId;
  final String courseId;
  final String sectionId;
  final String duration;
  final String isLessonFree;
  final String videoUrl;
  final String videoType;
  final String attachmentType;
  final dynamic attachment;

  factory LessonDetail.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LessonDetail(
        title: json["title"],
        lessonId: json["lesson_id"],
        courseId: json["course_id"],
        sectionId: json["section_id"],
        duration: json["duration"],
        isLessonFree: json["is_lesson_free"],
        videoUrl: json["video_url"],
        videoType: json["video_type"],
        attachmentType: json["attachment_type"],
        attachment: json["attachment"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "title": title,
        "lesson_id": lessonId,
        "course_id": courseId,
        "section_id": sectionId,
        "duration": duration,
        "is_lesson_free": isLessonFree,
        "video_url": videoUrl,
        "video_type": videoType,
        "attachment_type": attachmentType,
        "attachment": attachment,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the working around it. Making use of keys and values of the given Map object did the trick. Any optimization on this is highly appreciated.

Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

SectionDemoData sectionDemoDataFromMap(String str) =>
    SectionDemoData.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String sectionDemoDataToMap(SectionDemoData data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class SectionDemoData {
  SectionDemoData({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  final bool status;
  final String message;
  final SubSection data;

  factory SectionDemoData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SectionDemoData(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: SubSection.fromMap(json["data"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": data.toMap(),
      };
}

class SubSection {
  SubSection({
    required this.lessonList,
    required this.lessonName,
  });

  final List<Lesson> lessonList;
  final List<String> lessonName;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'lessonList': lessonList.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList()});

    return result;
  }

  factory SubSection.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return SubSection(
      lessonName: List.from(map["data"].keys), //Modified Code
      lessonList:
          List<Lesson>.from(map["data"].values.map((x) => Lesson.fromMap(x))), //Modified Code
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory SubSection.fromJson(String source) =>
      SubSection.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'SubSection(lesson: $lessonName,lessonList: ${lessonList.toString()})';
}

class Lesson {
  Lesson({
    required this.isLesson,
    required this.lessonDetailList,
  });

  final bool isLesson;
  final List<LessonDetail> lessonDetailList;

  factory Lesson.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Lesson(
        isLesson: json["is_lesson"],
        lessonDetailList: List<LessonDetail>.from(
            json["lesson_detail"].map((x) => LessonDetail.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "is_lesson": isLesson,
        "lesson_detail":
            List<dynamic>.from(lessonDetailList.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class LessonDetail {
  LessonDetail({
    required this.title,
    required this.lessonId,
    required this.courseId,
    required this.sectionId,
    required this.duration,
    required this.isLessonFree,
    required this.videoUrl,
    required this.videoType,
    required this.attachmentType,
    required this.attachment,
  });

  final String title;
  final String lessonId;
  final String courseId;
  final String sectionId;
  final String duration;
  final String isLessonFree;
  final String videoUrl;
  final String videoType;
  final String attachmentType;
  final dynamic attachment;

  factory LessonDetail.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LessonDetail(
        title: json["title"],
        lessonId: json["lesson_id"],
        courseId: json["course_id"],
        sectionId: json["section_id"],
        duration: json["duration"],
        isLessonFree: json["is_lesson_free"],
        videoUrl: json["video_url"],
        videoType: json["video_type"],
        attachmentType: json["attachment_type"],
        attachment: json["attachment"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "title": title,
        "lesson_id": lessonId,
        "course_id": courseId,
        "section_id": sectionId,
        "duration": duration,
        "is_lesson_free": isLessonFree,
        "video_url": videoUrl,
        "video_type": videoType,
        "attachment_type": attachmentType,
        "attachment": attachment,
      };
}
```